# Libcurl get parameters for use in PHP

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

In a curl api request how do I specify the a parameter for the api?

I have this and it works fine:

```
$url = "https://api.example.com/v2/contacts/649206813003";
...
$ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
  ...
curl_close($ch);
```

But I would like to use something like:

```
$url = "https://api.example.com/v2/contacts";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"id": "649206813003"}');
```

This doesn't work. I figure since this is a `GET` request `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is not what I want, but I can't find anything in libcurl for `GET`

Is this possible or do I just append my parameter to the URL?

Comment: urlencode the get params and append to the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use **GET** method then you can build query for your request.

For example

```
$url .= "?id=649206813003";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's as simple as:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=649206813003");
```

And, in case you have more parameters:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=649206813003&secondparameter=abc");
```